# Get ServletContext Connection to JSP

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, servlets

I am Connecting to the database at initialization of my Application through ServletContext Listener. I am able to utilize all the Connection I get from the database except the Connections where I am passing values direct to the JSP without Going through the servlet.

For Example I have a Vector Method in My DAO Class that returns a Collection of values which I am populating to a drop down in the JSP like this:

```
<jsp:useBean id="obj" class ="mypackage.MyDAOClass" scope="page"/>

......
```

My drop down

```
<c:forEach var ='item" items=${obj.campusCodes}">
<option>${item}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

I have set an attribute database in My ContextServletListener like this:

```
Connection conn = db.getDBConnection(url,sid,dbuser,dbpass,dbdriver,dbport,dbhost);
context.setAttribute("database", conn);
```

How Can I still be able to populate my drop down with this Arrangement or Do I need to change Anything?

Comment: As a general practice, connection checkouts should happen only in the _bean_ dedicated for DB operations. As it is something holding up a resource, that is _vulnerable_ of being left unclosed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use Session

```
session = request.getSession();
```

Comment: Are you sure I will get the same values from the session that I set with Context? An how Do I pass the value to the Method returning the Vector Collection?